# htaccess route multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess

I am starting a project which will require 8 websites to be hosted from one server/IP, using the same (custom) framework.

What I need to do is use separate app folders for each site. This part is easy, just duplicate the folder structure. The part I am having trouble with is the `.htaccess`.

Each application folder is set up like so:

```
- application
  -controller
  -view
  -www
    -css
    -js
    -img
```

Now, what needs to happen is that the requests for files need to be set up get them, and any request that is not a file goes to a bootstrap file for the individual application... Again this part is easy, as I have a `.htaccess` file in the webroot to handle that once the request gets there.

What I need is, in the main root folder, to use `.htaccess` to decide what application to go to based on the domain that the user visited.

When there is only one application folder to go to, my htaccess redirect section looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond     %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/www%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule     ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/                 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$  application/www/        [L]
RewriteRule (.*)    application/www/$1      [L]
```

basically, I need to replicate this for multiple domains using the same framework.

The application folders are named the same as the domain name, if that's any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST}/www%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ application/www/ [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST}/www%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST}/www%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/www/$1 [L]
```

The 2 conditions above the last rule ensure that the requested resource actually exists in the application's www folder, otherwise the 404 message would expose the folder structure.

You may need to canonicalize the hostnames with some rules (above these) like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to force hostnames to start with **www** or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to remove the **www** from the hostname.

Comment: I love quick, to the point answers, you've saved me a headache!

Also, if I could +2 your post I would because you've removed the actual need for a second `.htaccess` file. Your 'two conditions in the last rule' were what was in the individual `.htaccess` files for each app!